# Export to Quicktime VR in OsiriX

Tags: quicktime

I am using [OsiriX](http://www.osirix-viewer.com) (5.8.5 32-bit) to generate a 3D MIP from a series of DICOM images. According to the official site and every other site I have looked at, exporting a Quicktime VR is one click away. The MIP looks great, however I cannot see the option to export to Quicktime VR anywhere. I have seen the option in the user guides as a button in the toolbar (it looks somewhat 5 years old), though I can't imagine they'd take away such a handy feature.

Anyone else manage to find it?

Comment: The best I can do is a movie export to a .mov, which is an animated rotation of the 3D object.

Comment: Looking in the files of the application, I found the icon which appears in the user guides. Too bad it doesn't show up in the actual application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It's no where to be found in recent versions of OsiriX. I had to go back to OsiriX 4.0. Works beautifully though, however you need QT7 to open the files.